# mac osx littlesnitch blocking outgoing connections from ssh remote login

Tags: macos, ssh, firewall

I have setup remote ssh access on the rush in my development computer (OSX 10.6.8) before leaving my home for holiday yesterday. It is correctly setup, and I can access it via SSH, logging is as root or as my usual development account without problems.

However, when I am remotely logged in, my Firewall "little snitch" (i think) seems to be blocking any outgoing connections besides ssh itself, that is, if i do:

`ping www.google.com (`or whatever host I know responds to ping)

I always get a timeout.

I've tried to brute-force rename Little Snitch's directory in `/Library` and killing the daemon, but then I get "`Host is down`" for any outgoing connection

Any idea on how can I temporarily disable the firewall from ssh?? As i said, root access is no problem. I badly need to access my git repo at home!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it :P Just renaming Little Snitch system folder AND rebooting the computer seems to do the trick !

Comment: would love to find a better way, but +1 for thanks for documenting your experience with this issue